# Cut and paste files preserving directory structure in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cut-and-paste

I am having a directory having three levels of sub-directories in windows 7. I need to cut files from the last level sub-directories and paste them into a new parent directory, while preserving the directory structure. Please guide me how can I achieve this?

Please note that all solutions I have found on this forum refer to solutions in Unix and that too for copy and paste only. I need to figure out solution for window 7 and for cut and paste.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully, but do you mean you have files in, for example, `C:\Test\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3` you want to copy to `C:\Test2`, but you want them to copy with `Folder1\Folder2\Folder3` still intact?

Comment: precisely Jonno. That is exactly what I want. There might be around 15 files in each of Folder3. I need to cut and paste around 5 of them into the new folder based on certain extension.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a script (to log the folder hierarchy) or some third-party application that already has this ability... The biggest problem you'll hit is what happens if the folder already exists with the same files in?

Comment: The destination folder is a new folder. Completely empty. So the problem of folder of same files should not arise.

Comment: @amitchaudhary The other problem I'm wondering about is how it knows which folders to include - will it *always* be the top three you want? In my example above, it would need to know not to include `Test`?

Comment: the number of folders can vary. Suppose there is a root folder C:\Test. Within this root folder, then can be directory hierarchy of one folder or more than one folder. Any file which matches the my extension needs to be copied to new destination. A file may reside inside one level sub-directory or third level sub-directory. The cut and paste command or script would ideally need to check each sub-directory recursively. Also, maximum level of sub-directory inside root is 4.

Comment: Suppose I am moving files from C:\Test to C:\Test2. Then file C:\Test\Folder1\abc.txt needs to go to C:\Test2\Folder1\abc.txt and C:\Test|Folder2\Folder3\xyz.txt needs to go to C:\Test2\Folder2\Folder3\xyz.txt